# Hair behaves strangely when baking

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, baking, hair

So I have a character with hair that uses hair dynamics and while baking a scene where she gets up from laying down the hair sticks to the surface and also hangs in midair

Blend File:
https://puu.sh/xRqfu/fa187b5936.blend

Hair before baking
[image]

Hair getting stuck to floor before flinging upwards
[image]

Position the hair gets stuck in when character has finished moving and the hair is still
[image]

Hair settings:

[image]
[image]

The render deadline is next week so any help would be extremely appreciated >.<